# Is there a Dynamic weapon enchantment in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

Is there an existing official version or rough equivalent of the 4e magic Dynamic weapon in 5e?

The basic properties of a dynamic weapon allow the user to change it from one weapon to another.  *E.g.* Bow then a longsword then a dagger, etc.

Comment: related [hruthvir homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88015/23970)

Comment: what would be the point? Creatures resistant / vulnerable to piercing or bludgeoning are extremely rare.

Comment: it has less use in 5e mechanically and is more of a flavor thing.  in 4e i built the character around being a weapons master and battlefield control.  being able to exploit weapons features and feats.  he was a terror as changing the dynamic weapons weapon type had no effect on my action economy.  bow, then a whip, then a greataxe, etc all without having to draw a weapon.  in 5e the feats and other crunch are not the same so obviously it wouldn't work the same way.  but i like the idea of a high skilled combatant and a set of shape changing weapons

Comment: How did you get a bow? Dynamic weapon only allows melee weapons (IIRC)

Comment: my DM ruled, "that's stupid, it can transform into a whip but not a bow? that doesn't make any sense."  it did not supply ammo, had to carry that.  funnily enough he is the one that brought it up.  i was just going to just make do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Rod of Lordly Might

This Legendary magic item has the ability to transform into a variety of weapons  (among other features):

> If you press button 1, the rod becomes a *flame tongue*, as a fiery blade sprouts from the end opposite the rod's flanged head (you choose the type of sword).
>
> If you press button 2, the rod's flanged head folds down and two crescent-shaped blades spring out, transforming the rod into a magic battleaxe that grants a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.
>
> If you press button 3, the rod's flanged head folds down, a spear point springs from the rod's tip, and the rod's handle lengthens into a 6-foot haft, transforming the rod into a magic spear that grants a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.

### Try out the Pact of the Blade

At level 3, warlocks gain access to a pact boon. One of the options to choose from is the Pact of the Blade which says:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it.

In this way, you essentially have a weapon that can take any form. You can even get a few ranged weapons with a particular Eldritch Invocation called Improved Pact Weapon:

> Finally, the weapon you conjure can be a shortbow, longbow, light crossbow, or heavy crossbow.

Comment: It doesn't invalidate your answer, but I'm pretty sure Rod of Lordly Might was present in AD&D (and quite possibly the original D&D).

Comment: these are definitely some options.  also yes i remember the RoLM being in 3.5.   i don't remember the details though